# Using `pivot_longer with` `values_ptypes` in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

My question is simple:

I've been trying to use `pivot_longer` with `values_ptypes`:

This is my code:

```
df <-mtcars %>% rownames_to_column()
df[1,] %>% pivot_longer(everything(),names_to = 'My Values', values_ptypes = list(rowname = 'character'))

df[1,] %>% pivot_longer(everything(),names_to = 'My Values', values_ptypes = list(rowname = as.character))
```

I have this message: `Error: Can't combine rowname <character> and mpg <double>.`

The idea of `values_ptypes` is warning `pivot_longer` that I have a column that is a `character`, right?

Comment: Your sugestion works @akrun thanks, again. How can do this using `pivot_longer` and `values_ptypes` argument?

Comment: Following your suggestion, after pivot_longer I will have to use mutate again to change to double, right?

Comment: I see @akrun. Thanks again! Have a great new year!

Comment: what you are looking for is more or less `df[1,] %>% pivot_longer(everything(),names_to = 'My Values', values_transform = list(value = as.character))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Change `values_ptypes` to `values_transform` if you want to transform the class of your variables when pivoting.

---

So first, you get the error **not** because `values_ptypes` is misspecified, but because you are trying to put numeric and character values into one column, and `tidyr` doesn't know how to:

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- mtcars %>% tibble::rownames_to_column()

df[1, c(1:2)] %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(
    everything(),
    names_to = 'My Values'
  )

# > Error: Can't combine `rowname` <character> and `mpg` <double>.
```

Second: `values_ptypes` is used to **confirm** that your values are as expected, not to change them.

#### Fix

As @Onyambu commented, if you want to change your values you can use `values_transform`:

```r
df[1, ] %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(
    everything(),
    names_to = 'My Values',
    values_transform = list(value = as.character)
  )
```

Result:

```r
# A tibble: 12 x 2
   `My Values` value    
   <chr>       <chr>    
 1 rowname     Mazda RX4
 2 mpg         21       
 3 cyl         6        
 4 disp        160      
 5 hp          110      
 6 drat        3.9      
 7 wt          2.62     
 8 qsec        16.46    
 9 vs          0        
10 am          1        
11 gear        4        
12 carb        4
```

Comment: No need of the mutate function. Check my comment

Comment: Just do `df[1,] %>% pivot_longer(everything(),names_to = 'My Values', values_transform = list(value = as.character))`

Comment: Oh, you're right! I tried that, but I misspelled `value` as `values`. Such a simple mistake. I'll change my answer and credit you.